# Counting instances in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

So, I'm gearing up for a contest and I cant seem to figure out one of the practice problems.I got as far as importing all the data. I understand how to solve the problem in my head, just not how to put it into code. P.S. I am kind of new at programming.

The question: How many times does a dog bark in a certain time interval?

**EDIT: The program should be able to work for multiple dogs**

Things given to me:

1. The total number of dogs.
       int numofdog = q.nextInt();
2. The time for the first bark.

   ```
   int b = 0;
   ```
3. The time between each bark.

   ```
   int d = 4;
   ```
4. The time slot in which to count the number of barks. 4 - 10

So for example, There is only 1 dog. The dog first barks at 0, then at 4, then at 8.. and so on. The time slot I am counting is 4- 10. So the dog barks at 4 and 8. So in total the dog barks 2 times during 4 - 10.

I don't know how to continue to tackle this.

*Original Code*

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class dog {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int b = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int m =0;
Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);

int numofdog = q.nextInt();

while (numofdog-->0) {

     b = q.nextInt();  // First Bark
     d = q.nextInt();  // Time between barks
     x = q.nextInt();  // Starting of interval
     y = q.nextInt();  // Ending of interval    





int time [] = new int[y];             // Make an array
for (int a = 0; a < time.length; a++) {
   time[a] = a + 1;

   if (time [a] % d == 0 ) {

       count ++;
        }
    }
} 


System.out. println(count);
}

}
```

*Updated Code* (Still working on it)

I'll post my problem word by word here as well so all of us can understand

Dog Breeder bob, wants to know how many times his dog(s) bark in a certain time interval

Input. The first line of the input will be a single `int numofdog`, the number of dogs bob has. The next `numofdog` lines will each consist of two integers: b and d. `b` is the time of the first bark and `d` is the time between barks.  The next line of is a single integer `numberofintervals`. The next `numberofintervals` lines will consist of two integers, `x` and `y`. `x` is the start of the interval being measured and `y` is the end

Example Input

2                --- numofdogs

0 4              --- b and d for dog 1

2 5              --- b and d for dog 2

1                --- num of intervals being measured

4 8              --- x and y for the intervals.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class dog {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int b1 = 0;
    int b2 = 0;
    int d1 = 0;
    int d2 = 0;
    int x1= 0;
    int y1= 0;
    int x2= 0;
    int y2= 0;
    int count = 0;


Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);

int numofdog = q.nextInt();

while (numofdog-->0) {

     b1 = q.nextInt();  // First Bark (Dog 1)
     d1 = q.nextInt();  // Time between barks (Dog 1)
     b2 = q.nextInt();  // First Bark (Dog 2)
     d2 = q.nextInt();  // Time between barks (Dog 2)

}

    int numberofintervals = q.nextInt();

     while (numberofintervals -->0) {
     x1 = q.nextInt();  // Starting of interval
     y1 = q.nextInt();  // Ending of interval   
     x2 = q.nextInt();  // Starting of interval
     y2 = q.nextInt();  // Ending of interval   

     }

int time [] = new int[10000];             // Make an array, to represent time
for (int a = 0; a < time.length; a++) {
   time[a] = a + 1;

   if (time [a] % d1 == 0 || time [a] % d2 == 0) {

       count ++;
        }

    }
System.out.println(count);
} 



}
```

Comment: You're almost there. Now you need to calculate how many times the dog bark. I would suggest using a pencil and a piece of paper to design your algorithm first (this may involve doing math operations as well), and then move that into code. If your specific problem is about how to move the algorithm into code, then provide your algorithm and we will help you.

Comment: Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: I'm unsure where to go from here. Kind of new to this. I do get an error when I try to compare arrays.

Comment: You should move the code to process each case inside the `while (linestobeimported-->0)` statement. Otherwise you're only processing the last case.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I get an error on the comparison. I dont think I can compare two arrays with ==. What did that other guy mean by modulo?

Comment: Arrays can't be compared using `==`. Array elements can be compared using `==` (in case of primitive types) or using `equals` (in case of reference types). I would suggest you using a different algorithm, you don't need arrays to solve this problem.

Comment: To compare two arrays you do it item by item (in a for loop), try googling "How to compare 2 arrays in java". Modulo operation returns the residual of a division. (For example: 5/2 will return 1. Because 5/2 = 2 and residual is 1). I can't test your program right now. But hope this helps

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, Frakcool think I did it by adding a modulo operation. Thanks for all your help. Can someone check my code to be sure?

Comment: @f6e9a I would recommend to put your original code on the question AND make an answer with the new code, we'll be glad to upvote it (if solves question) or give feedback on it. And so you can accept it as an answer (and question marked as solved in that case). Will test in half an hour is nobody else tests it before.

Comment: @Frakcool ok, I will but I just tested my code and it only works for 1 dog. If I enter 2 it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: can you post an example with 2 dogs?

Comment: does each dog has diferent interval for each bark? do they bark at the same time for the 1st time? do they have the same start and end interval?

Comment: @Frakcool I added the complete problem along with my new code, which does not give me the right answer of 3. (3 is the right answer for the example input). Both dogs dont have the same interval or start time.

Comment: Is the 1st bark **always** before the start of interval? or it could be after it?

Comment: The first bark just tells you what the interval will be added to. Example: First bar is at 0, then all the other barks will in the pattern of 4. 0, 4, 8, 12... if the first bark was at 1, then all the barks would be at 5, 9, 13...

Comment: One more question, what's the desired output to the example input you gave? I guess I got it, but not sure until tested.

Comment: For the Example Input file the answer is 3. The first dog barks twice and the second dog barks once. giving us a total of 3 barks between 4 and 8 seconds. (inclusive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new code, you were thinking about 2 dogs, if there are 3 or more dogs, then your code won't work, so arrays are the solution to this problem.

Each dog has it's own `b`, `d` variables. Test it with more than 2 dogs and see what happens. If any error occurs just post it and I'll check it.

Your for loop wasn't the optimal since you were taking 0 as the interval start instead of your `x` and `y` (start and end) intervals.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NumberOfBarksTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numOfDog = 0;
        int b[] = new int[10]; //1st bark
        int d[] = new int[10]; //time between barks
        int numberOfIntervals = 0;
        int x[] = new int[10]; //start of interval
        int y[] = new int[10]; //end of interval
        int barks[] = new int[10];
        int totalBarks = 0;
        Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            barks[i] = 0;
        }

        numOfDog = q.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfDog; i++) {
            b[i] = q.nextInt();
            d[i] = q.nextInt();
        }

        numberOfIntervals = q.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfIntervals; i++) {
            x[i] = q.nextInt();
            y[i] = q.nextInt();
        }

        for(int dog = 0; dog < numOfDog; dog++) {
            for(int i = x[dog]; i <= y[dog]; i += d[dog]) {
                barks[dog]++;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfDog; i++) {
            System.out.println("Barks for dog " + i + ": " + barks[i]);
            totalBarks += barks[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Total barks: " + totalBarks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. Next time try to do your problem on paper, with 3 or more examples, put your logic there and it will be easier to translate your logic into code.